# ArcMap: interpolation for single polygons individually

Tags: raster, arcmap, polygon, interpolation

The red polygons in the image represent the boundary of infills. The raster (colored area) within the polygons is interpolated from the point shape file (black dots). The image shows an example where interpolation is performed across polygon boundaries. However, the values within polygon A should not affect the interpolation in polygons B-E and vice versa. Is there a straightforward way to restrict the interpolation to the polygons? I'd like to avoid to disassemble the points for each polygon and to assemble the result afterwards.

[image]

Comment: Before you run the interpolation geoprocessing tool, select the points you want to be involved in the selection. Remember all geoprocessing tools honour selections first.

Comment: I'd wish not to have to select the points manually for each polygon. However, maybe the solution is to do it this way iteratively in an arcpy-script.

Comment: A simple model with a feature iterator looping over polygon ID will do this, no need for any scripting or manual selection.